# Do planetary geared tuners obviate the need for tailpiece tuners?

Tags: string-instruments, orchestral-strings

I've read somewhere the claim that geared tuners (e.g Pegheds, Wittners) obviate the need for fine-tuners. Does this refer to the fine tuners that clamp onto the string, or does it also mean I can stop using the tailpiece fine-tuners altogether?

Comment: I googled pegheads - they are a geared replacement for the standard wooden tuning peg. Some players use only the wooden pegs with no fine tuners, whether clamped onto the string or attached to the tailpiece. Pegheads look as though they would make the mechanics of tuning easy, and make any other fine-tuners unnecessary.

Comment: Do what makes tuning comfortable for you.

Answer (score 2):

I have a violin with both geared tuners and fine-tuners, and the resolution of the geared tuners is certainly good enough to eliminate the need for fine-tuners.

However, I find that the strings sometimes get stuck at the nut, similarly to the problem that Les Paul guitars are known for. I'm not sure if this is a problem specific to my violin or if it is caused by the slower movement of the geared tuners, but I still use the fine tuners because of it.

Comment: If your strings are sticking, make sure the nut grooves don't have sharp edges, and also use some pencil lead to lubricate the  grooves.

Comment: Not just Les Paul guitars, in fact, not usually  Les Paul guitars.